# For random times $\tau_j(\omega):=\inf\{s\ge 0: A_s (\omega)>jT/n\}\wedge T$, $A_{\tau_j}-A_{\tau_{j-1}}=T/n$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

This is part of a proof of a Theorem from Schilling's Brownian Motion.

Let $A_s$ be a continuous weakly increasing process. Given a partition of points $t_j$, define random times $\tau_j(\omega):=\inf\{s\ge 0: A_s (\omega)>jT/n\}\wedge T,j\ge 1,$ and $\tau_0(\omega)=0$.

In this case, how does the continuity of $s\mapsto A_s$ ensure that $A_{\tau_j}-A_{\tau_{j-1}}=T/n$ for all $1\le j \le \lfloor nA_T/T\rfloor$?

This identity clearly holds in the case that $\tau_j(\omega) <T$, but how do we ensure this when we might have $\tau_j$ or $\tau_{j-1}=T$?

Comment: The point is that we may not "have $\tau_j$ or $\tau_{j-1}=T$" when $j$ is small enough, namely when $j\leqslant nA_T/T$.

Comment: @Did What I understand is when $j\le nA_T /T$ we have $A_T \ge jT/n$. So in the case $A_T > jT/n$, we must have $\tau_j$ and $\tau_{j-1} <T$. But how about in the case $A_T = jT/n$? How do we ensure that we have $\tau_j$ and $\tau_{j-1}<T$ here? Because otherwise, we may not get $A_{\tau_j} - A_{\tau_{j-1}}=T/n$.

Comment: On the event $[A_T=jT/n]$ one knows that $A_{\tau_{j-1}}=(j-1)T/n$ and $A_{\tau_j}=jT/n$, so where is the problem?